# How to specify a linear programming-like constraint (i.e. max number of rows for a dimension's attributes) in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I'm looking to assign unique person IDs to a marketing program, but need to optimize based on each person's Probability Score (some people can be sent to multiple programs, some only one) and have two constraints such as budgeted mail quantity for each program.

I'm using SQL Server and am able to put IDs into their highest scoring program using the `row_number() over(partition by person_ID order by Prob_Score)`, but I need to return a table where each ID is assigned to a program, but I'm not sure how to add the max mail quantity constraint specific to each individual program. I've looked into the Check() constraint functionality, but I'm not sure if that's applicable.

```
create table test_marketing_table(
    PersonID int,
    MarketingProgram varchar(255),
    ProbabilityScore real
);

insert into test_marketing_table (PersonID, MarketingProgram, ProbabilityScore)
values (1, 'A', 0.07)
       ,(1, 'B', 0.06)
       ,(1, 'C', 0.02)
       ,(2, 'A', 0.02)
       ,(3, 'B', 0.08)
       ,(3, 'C', 0.13)
       ,(4, 'C', 0.02)
       ,(5, 'A', 0.04)
       ,(6, 'B', 0.045)
       ,(6, 'C', 0.09);

--this section assigns everyone to their highest scoring program,
--but this isn't necessarily what I need
with x
as
(
select *, row_number()over(partition by PersonID order by ProbabilityScore desc) as PersonScoreRank
from test_marketing_table
)
select *
from x
where PersonScoreRank='1';
```

I also need to specify some constraints: two max C packages, one max A & one max B package can be sent. How can I reassign the IDs to a program while also using the highest probability score left available?
The final result should look like:

```
PersonID    MarketingProgram    ProbabilityScore    PersonScoreRank
3               C                 0.13                  1
6               C                 0.09                  1
1               A                 0.07                  1
6               B                 0.045                 2
```

Comment: Why not `3  B  0.08` which is higher then `6 B 0.045`?

Comment: You haven't told us anything about what mail quantity is or where that data would come from, so we cannot really answer your question about how to apply a max constraint on it for a program.

Comment: @serg because personID 3 was already used for marketing to program C. I forgot to mention that each person could only be marketed to one program. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your desired final result shows person 6 which is marketed to two programms B and C. The accepted answer will give you person 3 in two programs as well. Not clear yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rethink your `ROW_NUMBER()` formula based on your actual need, and you should also have a table of Marketing Programs to make this work efficiently. This covers the basic ideas you need to incorporate to efficiently perform the filtering you need.

**MarketingPrograms Table**

```
CREATE TABLE MarketingPrograms (
    ProgramID varchar(10),
    PeopleDesired int
    )
```

**Populate the MarketingPrograms Table**

```
INSERT INTO MarketingPrograms (ProgramID, PeopleDesired) Values
    ('A', 1),
    ('B', 1),
    ('C', 2)
```

**Use the MarketingPrograms Table**

```
with x as (
    select *, 
        row_number()over(partition by ProgramId order by ProbabilityScore desc) as ProgramScoreRank
    from test_marketing_table
    )
select *
from x
INNER JOIN MarketingPrograms m
   ON x.MarketingProgram = m.ProgramID
WHERE x.ProgramScoreRank <= m.PeopleDesired
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe that this is the solution I'm looking for.